# PhpMyAdmin often (but not always) fails with "Error (rejected): It seems that the connection to server has been lost"

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mariadb, debian

I have a fresh install of a Debian 11 server with the full LAMP set:

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket (no SSL)
- Server type: MariaDB 10.5.19-MariaDB-0+deb11u2
- Apache/2.4.56 (Debian)
- Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.33
- PHP extension: mysqli Documentation mbstring Documentation sodium Documentation
- PHP version: 7.4.33
- phpMyAdmin version: 5.2.1

When I work on phpMyAdmin it happens that sometimes (if not often) when scrolling a table or opening a new window/command an error message appears stating:

> *Error in processing request Error text: error (rejected) It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network
> connectivity and server status.*

Of course, the network connectivity works fine and the server is always up & running.
The weird thing is that the error is not systematic but happens randomly and not always after the same action made on phpMyAdmin.
When browsing  a quite big table page-by-page, the error may happen on the 1st page or on the 7th or on the n-th, unpredictably.
More often it happens almost immediately when accessing the "SQL" Tab where I am definitely unable to run even a simple query.

The apache2 logs don't say anything on the problem and I have just enabled also MariaDB error logs to write file on /var/log but so far nothing has been logged.
Following a post found on web I tried to raise the PHP parameter "memory_limit" from <128M> (default) to <512M> but also this action did not get any improvement on phpMyAdmin behaviour.

How to fix this problem?